# Thymeleaf - Iterating over a model attribute inside Javascript code

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to write some Javascript code where I need to use a model attribute. Here is how I define the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    //need some loops

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

What I need to do is, using `each` iterations over model attributes inside the script. So far I couldn't manage to do this with `th:each`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @sgpalit Assume it contains a list of strings. I need to iterate over the String list and map each string to another.

Comment: Do you use the `JSP`?

Comment: I'm using Thymeleaf.

Comment: Do you try parse your model to a `JSON` object? and use `Thymeleaf` to iterate. I am not familar with `Thymeleaf`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I guess you need to wrap your model attrubite in double brackets, like this: `[[${modelAttribute}]]`. The script inlining section of the Thymeleaf docs can help a bit:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var theList = [[${modelAttribute}]]
    for (i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
        doSomething(theList[i]);
    }

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: So if you have a lot of elements in the list and the class representing an element contains a lot of members you end up with a huge chunk of JavaScript even if you just need to retrieve only 1 property... That also sucks if there are sensitive properties in your element, they'll show up in JavaScript. Is there a better way to loop through the list and hold the current element in a local Thymeleaf variable like with JSP/JSTL?

Answer (score 18):

You can also do like this, which is the most compact I guess:

In your `@Controller`:

```
model.addAttribute("items", new String[] { "item1", "item2", "item3" });
```

In your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

var items = [];

/*[# th:each="n : ${items}"]*/

items.push("[(${n})]");

/*[/]*/

</script>
```

Other useful stuff is explained here: [[MAJOR FEAT] New syntax for textual template modes #395](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/395)

Comment: Thanks for flagging this up - I've failed to get the th:each working inline, but I'm sure that's my novicey use of Thymeleaf. It's a good feature and would remove @maxime's worries in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Thymeleaf 3** -> see yglodt answer

if you're stuck with **Thymeleaf 2** and your model attribute is complex (like the case of Maxime Laval), I ended up looping over a script :

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  var dataLayer = [];
</script>
<script th:each="item:${items}" th:inline="javascript">
  dataLayer.push({'attr1':item.attr1, 'attr2':item.attr2, 'attr3':item.attr3});
</script>
<script th:inline="javascript">
  console.log(dataLayer); // do whatever you want with dataLayer...
</script>
```

Not very nice but I couldn't find better for my Google analytics.

Answer (score 1):

This works with me in latest version of thymeleaf by adding `/*[[${name}]]*/`

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var theList = /*[[${modelAttribute}]]*/
    for (i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
        doSomething(theList[i]);
    }

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

thymeleaf converts object into javascript variable within the script tag, so can access properties using javascript codes. no need to worry about th:

```
     <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
                            /*<![CDATA[*/
                            //the list converts as a javascript object
                            var availableTypes = /*[[${dataList}]]*/;
                            console.log(availableTypes);
                            /*]]>*/
     </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you are stuck with Thymeleaf 2 is absusing the "th:block"-Element within your Script-Tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var arrayOfIds= [
        <th:block th:each="element: ${list}" th:inline="text">[[${element.Id}]],</th:block>
            -1 
        ];
        arrayOfIds.pop(); // Remove the superflous last Element
    </script>
```